# How to list all personal sharepoint sites using microsoft graph?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, site, api, microsoft-graph

I want to fetch following data using Microsoft graph API

1. All the root sites(group + personal)
2. All group root sites
3. All personal root sites

For the first case currently I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites` in order to find out all the root sites

For the second one I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=contentclass:STS_Site` to find out all group sites.

I am not sure how to which API I can use to find out only personal sites. Do graph API have any filter which does that? Also is there a way to solve point 1 and 2 in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with you and I asked on yesterday [Get members of site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281160/how-to-get-members-of-root-site-and-communication-site-with-graph-api)

But it seems no way to get members of site on Microsoft Graph API. We need to use SharePoint REST API to get it. I finding out the way to apply the SharePoint REST API with Azure App Registration.