# How to obtain permissions, via MS Graph API, for a Communication Sites & its pages?

Tags: permissions, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I have a Communications Site with pages, and I am trying to understand if I can obtain the Sharepoint identities via the MS Graph API.

My understanding is that a Communication Site is not represented as an Office 365 Group and their are Sharepoint specific groups which are referenced by these. As per docs[1]:

> Communication sites - Communication sites are for broadcasting news and status across the organization. Communication site permissions are managed by using the SharePoint Owners, Members, and Visitors groups for the site.

What I am trying to do:

- Get a list of the SP Users, Groups, or Claims which make up the access for a Communication Site and its pages
- Relate those users, groups, or claims back to respective Entra ID entries (I can ignore external users, so I am assuming these users exist in Entra)

Previously, there have been posts which ask a similar question of mine, and the answer was "This data is not yet available in the MS Graph API"[2], but that was 2-3 years ago and the API has improved significantly.

If it's a non-Communications Site, I am able to obtain what I need. This is because the MS Graph API provides the Entra ID references to the user/groups as per site access. No where in the API responses do I see how this is possible for a Communications Site, so I must be missing something.

The User Information List (`...User Information List/items?$expand=fields`) also does not provide insight.

Is this a case where I must use the Sharepoint API? Are there open issues I can follow which provide a plan of migration for this to be available in the MS Graph API?

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions
2. [How to get members of Root Site and Communication Site with Graph API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281160/how-to-get-members-of-root-site-and-communication-site-with-graph-api)

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-your-sharepoint-communication-site-21761aac-f7f7-4499-b0ca-cf283477c32f

Have you tried using the /sites/{site-id}/permissions endpoint in the Microsoft Graph API? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-get-permission?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: I ended up using the SharePoint API, which is the only way to obtain this data (at this point in time and per my understanding)